# Jmeter(Unable to run Jmeter in Ubuntu Amazon Instance)

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter, ubuntu-12.04

While running Jmeter in Ubuntu Amazon Instance, I am getting the following error--

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-219:~/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.9/bin$ jmeter
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate commons-net in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate geronimo-activation-1.1-spec in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate geronimo-javamail-1.4-provider in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate jboss-j2ee in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate jdom1 in /usr/share/java
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: No JAVA_CMD set for run_java, falling back to JAVA_CMD = java
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access /usr/share/jmeter/lib/junit
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:96)
An error occurred: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I don't know where exactly the problem is . Can any one please help?

Thanks,
Vimal

Comment: I get an identical error when my -p input file had bad syntax. So the error shown in your terminal is probably not helpful here. Examine the file jmeter.log for more useful information. The file should be created in the directory from where jmeter has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to start the GUI version of JMeter and not the NON GUI version.
If you want to run JMeter on the commandline, you can take a look at this page: http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/using-apache-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/

Answer (score 1):

```
jmeter -n -t MyTestPlan.jmx
```

-n ensures it runs in non-GUI mode.

You should see something like -

```
Created the tree successfully using Post Request.jmx
Starting the test @ Mon Jun 02 16:10:44 IST 2014 (1401705644820)
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
Tidying up ...    @ Mon Jun 02 16:10:47 IST 2014 (1401705647509)
... end of run
```